# What am I supposed to say?

Tags: usage

What am I supposed to say when 6hours felt like 1 hour to me. Is it true if i say “it doesn’t felt so long”? I’m confused about felt or feel?

Comment: *It did not feel that long.*

Comment: The time flew by. Conversely, time really dragged.

Comment: The auxiliary verb (*do*) is inflected for tense but not its accompanying main verb. So "It doesn't feel so long" or "It didn't feel so long." The main verb (*feel*) stays in the plain form.